# PHP contact form submitting but not receiving email

Tags: php, html, form-submit, contact-form

I realise this question has been asked numerous times before but everyone's code is obviously different and I am quite new to php so just looking to see if someone can give me some help.

I have created a basic contact form for a site but for some reason the information is not being sent to my email address although I believe that the form is submitted?

my PHP code is:

```
<?php
session_start();
//$to_mail = "architects@palavin.com,t.lavin@palavin.com,12yorkcourt@gmail.com";
$to_mail = "danny@enhance.ie";
//$cc="paul@enhance.ie";
$mail_sent = 0;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //echo "the form was submitted";

$error= array();

$name = trim(strip_tags($_POST['name']));
if($name == "")
    $error['name'] = 1;

$email = trim(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
if($email == "")
    $error['email'] = 1;

$phone = trim(strip_tags($_POST['phone']));

$address = trim(strip_tags($_POST['address']));

$description = trim(strip_tags($_POST['description']));

$str = trim(strip_tags($_POST['secu']));
if ( isset($_SESSION['code_']) && $_SESSION['code_'] == strtoupper($str)){} else {$error['secu'] = 1;}


if(empty($error)){
    $headers = 'From: "Euro Insulation" <no-reply@euroinsulations.ie>'."\r\n";
    //$headers .= 'CC: "'.$cc.'" <'.$cc.'>'."\r\n";
    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "";



    $subject = "New contact message";

    $message = "New Contact message, received from: <br /> \n ";
    $message .= "<b>Name</b> ".$name."<br /> \n";
    $message .= "<b>Email</b> ".$email."<br /> \n";

    $message .= "<b>Phone</b> ".$phone."<br /> \n";
    $message .= "<b>Address</b> ".$address."<br /> \n";

    $message .= "<b>Description</b> ".$description."<br /> \n";

    if(@mail($to_mail,$subject,$message,$headers ))
    {
        echo "mail sent";
        $mail_sent = 1;
    }
    else echo "mail not sent";
}

}

?>
```

my html form looks like this:

```
<table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
                <tr>
                  <td width="65%" valign="top"><p class="header"><br>
        Contact US <br>
                  </p>
                      <?php if($mail_sent==1){
    print "Thank you for your message.";
} else { ?>
<form class="email_sub" method="post" >

<table width="77%"  border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td><label for="name" class="formtext" <?php if($error['name']==1) echo "style='color:red;'" ?> >Name:</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="name" id="text"  <?php if($name) echo "value='".$name."'" ?>  /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="phone" class="formtext">Number:</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"/><tr>
<br />

<tr>
<td><label for="email" class="textarea" <?php if($error['email']==1) echo "style='color:red;'" ?>>Email:</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="email" id="email"  <?php if($email) echo "value='".$email."'" ?>  /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><br /></td>
</tr>

<tr><td><label for="address" class="textarea">Address/Location of project:</label></td>
<td><textarea rows="3" cols="20" name="address" id="address" style="width: 400px;"><?php if($address!="") echo $address ?></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><br /></td>
</tr>
<br />
<tr>
<td><label for="description" class="fixedwidth">Enquiry</label></td>
<td><textarea rows="3" cols="20" name="description" id="description" style="width: 400px;"><?php if($description!="") echo $description; ?></textarea></td>
<tr>
<td><br /></td>
</tr>

<!-- form -->
<tr>
<td><label>&nbsp;</label></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

Am i missing something obvious here?? Any help will really be appreciated thanks!

Comment: first obvious question: is your server setted for sending mails?

Comment: "I believe that the form is submitting"... Are you seeing your page reload and display the messages you expect?. Also, as said above?. Have you checked your server settings?. Try creating a naked php file that sends a mail and does nothing else.

Comment: Yes the page definitely reloads once i click submit but nothing else is happening? At the end of my php code i set it to print out "mail sent" or "mail not sent" but it does'nt print either in the console in Chrome? i take it its not even getting this far then? How do go about creating and sending a naked file? Sorry like i said quite new to this!

Comment: Is $error empty after form submission?

Comment: how do you mean? After submission nothing is happening but there are no errors showing up in the console anyway?

Comment: Hm nothing looks like very wrong with code above. You have some "echo" in your code so after you submit your form do you get any echo like "mail sent" or "mail not sent" or anything? If you get "mail sent" echo after submitting then there is probably something wrong with server configuration or you are unable to send mails or you get mail in JUNK folder or anything. If you don't get any echo then try any other code or somebody just answered you with the code bellow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used sessions which is not required here, you can also use flag variable instead of arrays in this simple form, use this updated code.

```
<?php
//$to_mail = "architects@palavin.com,t.lavin@palavin.com,12yorkcourt@gmail.com";
$to_mail = "danny@enhance.ie";
//$cc="paul@enhance.ie";
$mail_sent = 0;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //echo "the form was submitted";

$name = trim(strip_tags($_POST['name']));
if($name == "")
    $error = true;

$email = trim(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
if($email == "")
    $error = true;

$phone = trim(strip_tags($_POST['phone']));
$address = trim(strip_tags($_POST['address']));
$description = trim(strip_tags($_POST['description']));


if($error != true){
    $headers = 'From: "Euro Insulation" <no-reply@euroinsulations.ie>'."\r\n";
    //$headers .= 'CC: "'.$cc.'" <'.$cc.'>'."\r\n";
    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "";

    $subject = "New contact message";

    $message = "New Contact message, received from: <br /> \n ";
    $message .= "<b>Name</b> ".$name."<br /> \n";
    $message .= "<b>Email</b> ".$email."<br /> \n";

    $message .= "<b>Phone</b> ".$phone."<br /> \n";
    $message .= "<b>Address</b> ".$address."<br /> \n";

    $message .= "<b>Description</b> ".$description."<br /> \n";

    if(@mail($to_mail,$subject,$message,$headers))
    {
        echo "mail sent";
        $mail_sent = 1;
    }
    else echo "mail not sent";
} else {
    echo 'validation error';
}
}
?>
```

You have also missed out the else statement for your form validation test so no errors getting displayed when you submit form.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the at sign from mail function and see what errors your get. @mail suppresses errors from being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Comment out the following line: if ( isset($*SESSION['code*']) && $*SESSION['code*'] == strtoupper($str)){} else {$error['secu'] = 1;}

You should be able to reach the mail function.