# Not receiving any email

Tags: php, html, contact-form

Hi I saw an online php tutorial and not able to receive any email from this contact form and not able to understand where I was wrong

```
<html>
  <head></head>
    <body>

        <?php 
            if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
                $email = $_POST['email'];
                $subject = $_POST['subject'];
                $message = $_POST['message'];
                mail("abcsojf@gmail.com",$subject, $message, "From:" . $email);
            }
        ?>

        <h1>Contact Us</h1>
        <form method="post" action="abc.html">
            <table align="center" style="color:#fff;">
                <tr><td style="color:black">Email:<input type="text" name="email" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td style="color:black">subject:<input type="text" name="subject" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td style="color:black">Message:<br>
                <textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="15">Type your message here</textarea>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send" /></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your form is posting to an HTML file?

Comment: Did you check the return value of the `mail` call? Did you look into the spam folder? Did you look at the mail log of the sending host?

Comment: Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Comment: Please [stop abusing tables for layout](http://designshack.net/articles/10-css-form-examples/)

Comment: Where are you testing?? localhost or any hosted server??

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP contact form submitting but not receiving email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18227429/php-contact-form-submitting-but-not-receiving-email)

Comment: i wanted to add this to my website so i really have no idea but when i added this code to my website and it sends no email
@Oswald I have checked the spam folder as well

Comment: You should not include request variables without any validation to send email. This can be easily abused and you will get into trouble when your mail server is used as a spam cannon.

Comment: `action = abc.html` seriously?

Comment: @DanFromGermany i'm just learning php now only sorry will make changes

Comment: Either split your HTML/PHP into 2 parts while naming your PHP handler file to `abc_handler.php` and set your action to `<form method="post" action="abc_handler.php">`or use that entire code "as is", name it `abc.php` and use `<form method="post" action="">` `.html` types will not process as PHP "unless" you TELL IT to TREAT IT as `.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three possible way to make it working. in which you have to follow first one compulsory.

1) Rename your file from abc.html -> abc.php and also check whether PHP is available and working over your localhost/hosted server.

2) Change your form tag to

```
<form name="mailform" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"> OR
<form name="mailform" method="post" action="">
```

to make your posted data available over same page.

3) Instead of

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
```

condition try to use

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["subject"])){
```

with Null value checking. This will ensure data availability in mail function. Also try to extend mail function with below headers.

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers = 'From: '.$email . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail("abcsojf@gmail.com",$subject, $message, $headers);
```

By following these three steps you will hopefully get your desired mail.

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the page though:

- A web server (So no `file:///` URIs)
- with PHP installed
- with PHP configured to process the file (servers that process files with `.html` extensions with PHP are very rare).

Comment: And if u are on windows with a valid SMTP server configuration in your PHP.ini

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work if you do the following two things :

1. Since you are submitting to same page, you can remove the action part.

   ```
   <form method="post" action="">
   ```
2. Save your current page as a .php file.

Your page will be `abc.php`

Now run your page in browser and submit the form.

p.s : You would need to have apache running with php installed.

You can check  this by creating a new page with the following contents :

```
<?php phpinfo();?>
```

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I have changed like you said and added it to my website jhcsnagpur.com
1)click on visionaries
2)click on visionaries again

Answer (score 0):

First of all, sending mail via PHP with default settings requires installed and configured Sendmail service on server.
In unix servers you can check `/usr/spool/mail/username` file, or `/var/log/maillog` for log of mail() "usage".